# Can I use the Openvpn Access Server WEB GUI on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: openvpn

Is the openvpn web-gui working on ubuntu 12.04?
See [access-server: download openvpn for Ubuntu](http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/download-openvpn-as-sw/113.html?osfamily=Ubuntu) on openvpn.net.
On the link above i only see support for ubuntu 10 and below.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the webgui works, up to 14.04 (possibly later, haven't checked it)

The "hard part" is configuring the ubuntu client because the network manager GUI won't fully read the client.ovpn file. You have to extract the necessary four certificates into separate files

In this case Have a look at the documentation for the sacli command.

http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/docs/admin-guides/228-how-to-extract-the-ca-cert-and-key-from-openvpn-as-certificates.html